# No 'going' button showing on Facebook event

Tags: facebook-events

I've created a public event on Facebook but it is only giving an Interested option to select. Even clicking again on Interested doesn't bring up Going ... it only shows Interested or Not Interested as options. How do I get the Going button to appear for people to select?

Comment: Doesn't it only show "Going" if you set the event to request RSVP?